# Regular expression edit css file Autoit

Tags: autoit

I would like to edit a css file dynamically using StringRegExpReplace.

Replace the image "background.png" with my variable $image.

example

```
$css = FileOpen("\css\styles2.css")
$read = FileReadLine($css,3)
$image = "myimage.jpg"
$replace = StringReplace($read,"background-image: url('background.jpg');","$image")
```

Thanks to all

Comment: so it is only when "background-image: url(" part appear that you want to change background.jpg or is it just background.jpg in general?

Comment: I have to replace the text in quotes because the name of the image is always different. background-image: url('xxxxxx.jpg');.... maybe '.*'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "background-image: url('background.jpg');31232132 background-image: url('backgroun2131231d.1jp123g');"
$image = "myimage.jpg"
$replace = StringRegExpReplace($str,"background-image\:\s*url\('(.*?)'\)","background-image: url\('" &  $image & "')")
ConsoleWrite($replace & @crlf)
```